# ZF2: Injecting Session management into a service

Tags: session, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I'm familiar with how to use the Session in ZF2, e.g.

```
        $user_session = new Container('user');
        $user_session->username = 'JohnDoe';
```

This is fine, but if I'm trying to persist session data in one of my business logic services I'd strongly prefer to inject a session management object/service into my service's constructor, like in this pseudocode:

```
class BusinessSvc{
   protected $sessionSvc;

   function __construct($sessionSvc){
      $this->sessionSvc = $sessionSvc;
   }

   public function doBusinessLayerStuff(){
      ... do stuff ...
      $this->sessionSvc->store('lastOrderNumber', '1234');
      ... do stuff ...
   }
}
```

I would think the framework would provide this functionality, but I can't find it anywhere.  I could always write my own, but didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean; the session containers, being name-spaced, *is* the session 'service', there is no need to wrap another class around them - i.e you can add, remove from the container at will. If you were to create a factory for each container then you can then reuse each one by injecting it into other services (so in your example `$sessionSvc` would be an instance of `Zend\Session\Container`). If you want to manage session handling globally then check out [`Zend\Session\SessionManager`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Session/SessionManager.php)

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps you're right; I can just instantiate a Container in my Module.php and pass it to the service's constructor that way. I was missing the forest for the trees I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was a lot simpler than I realized. Once instantiated, a Container instance itself can be injected into the business service and provide it with access to the session.  If using phpunit to later test the service, the object could be mocked with an array or an instance of ArrayObject.

In Module.php's getServiceConfig method:

```
 'MyModule\Service\BusinessService' => function($sm) {
      // Container doesn't need to use this name but it seems sensible.
      $container = new Container('MyModule\Service\BusinessService');
      return new Service\BusinessService($container);
 },
```